# Convert and re-stream HLS stream

Tags: python, streaming, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

**What I'm trying to do:**

- I have devices that (i) can't hit the internet and (ii) are using software 
  than cannot read HLS playlist/streams.
- I have a server that will sit between these devices and the internet.
- I want it to read in the HLS stream from outside and re-package the actual audio content into something that can be streamed by the other devices.

**What I've got:**

```
import m3u8
import requests

print("hello")

mus = "http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_6music.m3u8"
m = m3u8.load(mus)
r_cache = []
for p in m.playlists:
    r1 = requests.get(p.uri)
    for a in r1.text.split('\n'):
        if a and not a.startswith('#'):
            full = "{}/{}".format(p.base_path, a)
            print("Downloading {}".format(full))
            r2 = requests.get(full)
            r_cache.append(r2)

for i, r in enumerate(r_cache):
    with open('file{}'.format(i), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

print("bye")
```

Please excuse the ugliness, this is just proof of concept. So I know I can take an HLS url, parse/use it to get the actual files and grab them.

**Where I'm stuck**
So how do I turn that into a single stream of data that can be read by other clients? I can save it to a single file, easy.

I've looked at the Python `Buffer` class and had a good read of [the IO module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) but I can't see anything that's quite what I want.

In my head I want:

- A buffer of some sort that I can write to continuously...
- ...that will only store the last `x` bytes of content
- ...that can be read from *without removing the content* by one or many clients.

*I'm not interested in transcoding etc. for the moment. Let's just assume the clients can read whatever actual audio they stream from me*

Comment: Without knowing the particulars of stream, I'd highly suggest looking at ffmpeg. It can convert formats without necessarily transcoding. Check out the [ffmpeg streaming guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide).

Comment: Cheers. My main problem is really how to offer up a stream. i.e. I've got loads of data coming in, how do I then provide that to a client?

Comment: That really depends on what formats the client can handle, but unless it's something really esoteric, you shouldn't need to write your own streaming server from scratch. The concept should really be: 1. decode the HLS into whatever format (probably m4a) 2. present a stream of that to your clients (over HTTP, RTMP, etc.). Do some research into ffmpeg and ffserver, I think you'll find what you need.